# "Must use destructuring state assignment": How to destructure from object and place on property inside object literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In a React project, I'm wanting to quickly troubleshoot things by logging specific parts of state at certain times.

```js
console.error('this.state.thing', this.state.thing);
```

Doing this, My ESLint config gives me the error "Must use destructuring state assignment". So, I would have to either turn this ESLint rule off, or I would have to do this:

```js
const { thing } = this.state;
console.error('this.state.thing', thing);
```

This is fine, but it made me wonder if I can destructure a property in the same way inside of an object literal in one go:

```js
const objectLiteral = {
  thing: this.state.thing, // how to destructure thing out of state?
  stuff1,
  stuff2: otherData,
};

const somethingLikeThis = {
  thing: ({ thing } = this.state),
}
```

Just curious if there is a way to do this.

Comment: I've seen a proposal somewhere to support `{ this.state.thing, ... }`, but I can't find it anymore, so it seems that this is not going to be specified.

Comment: @JonasWilms https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements#object-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it through arrow function

```
console.error('this.state.thing', (obj => obj.thing)(this.state))
```

Comment: This answer really helped me grasp functional programming a lot more. Guessing someone downvoted this because it's not formatted in a way that directly answers the question, but `thing: (obj => obj.thing)(this.state)` works.

Comment: There s no problem if someone downvoted it, this issue is not such a big importance...I like and respect FP too, so i love things like this

Answer (score 1):

Not inside the literal, but you can destructure values into object properties:

```
({thing: objectLiteral.thing} = this.state);
```